# Change SQL Connectivity in Azure using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to change/set SQL connectivity to Public(Internet) in a SQL Server azure vm while deploying sql vm or once deployed using powershell?

[image]

Part of my provisioning script looks like this. Will updating something in `$vmConfig` work?

```
# Create SQL Server
    $vmConfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $ServerName -VMSize 'Standard_D2_v2' | `
    Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $adminCredentials -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate | `
    Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -PublisherName "MicrosoftSQLServer" -Offer "SQL2017-WS2016" -Skus "SQLDEV" -Version "latest" | `
    Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -Name $osDiskName -VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption "FromImage" | `
    Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id

# Add SQL Server VM extension
   New-AzureRmVM -VM $vmConfig -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location
   Set-AzureRmVMSqlServerExtension -Name "SqlIaasExtension" -Version "1.2" -VMName $ServerName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -Location $Location
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried configuring the deployment in the portal and downloading the resulting ARM template?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I haven't yet. I am just looking for a powershell command for now if any or some quick work around. I am considering ARM as the last option. I have downloaded automation script but cannot see any relevant setting in template or powershell command in deploy.ps1.

Comment: Enabling SQL Auth, and external IP connectivity require multiple steps to be run inside the VM after it's booted, so I don't think you can accomplish that with the ARM cmdlets.  The difference between Public and VNet connectivity is just in the NSG, so you should be able to configure that.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I can't see any difference between NSG rules before and after changing connectivity from private to public. Is it documented any where?

Comment: I don't know.  But the VM doesn't know anything about the public IP, so it must be configured somewhere in the Azure networking.